# Get bullets to show up on the EZ-Pages in Zen Cart

Tags: php, zen-cart

I can not find any reason as to why bullets will not appear on the EZ-pages in Zen Cart.

They show up in the editor that I use but not when the page is loaded on the site.

Has anyone else had this problem? Is it a bug?

Comment: To get an answer, you probably need to provide more details and/or a link to a live page.

Comment: I agree with @thirtydot, however, if I can make a shot in the dark you might want to check your CSS, specifically related to UL or LI elements, setting a list-style-type:none; attribute.

Comment: See if `ul { list-style: disc !important; padding-left: 36px !important }` makes them appear. If it does, apply the same thing less stupidly using a proper selector and without `!important`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Give a man a fish....)

Here's how to find the CSS attribute:

1. Open Chrome (or Firefox if you have the Firebug extension installed)
2. Right-click the list, click Inspect Element
3. Make sure you are looking at the styles for `<li>`
4. In the CSS pane, look for `list-style: none` or `list-style-type: none`, find that in your CSS file (file name and line number is shown beside it) and change it to `list-style:disc`